When is a simplex open in $\lvert K \rvert$?
The question is from Chapter 1 Section 2 exercise 1 in James Munkres Elements of Algebraic Topology .
Here is the whole question:Let $K$ be a simplicial complex;let $\sigma\in K$. When is Int $\sigma$ open in $\lvert K\rvert$? When is $\sigma$ open in $\lvert K\rvert$?
Here is my attempt:(1)Int $\sigma$ is always open in $\lvert K\rvert$.
$\forall \tau\in K,$ we have,
$\begin{align}\tau\cap(\lvert K\rvert\setminus Int\sigma)&=(\tau\cap\lvert K\rvert)\setminus(\tau\cap Int\,\sigma)\\&=\tau\setminus(\tau\cap Int\,\sigma)\\
&=\tau\setminus Int\,\sigma
\end{align}$
Case 1:$\tau\cap\sigma=\emptyset,\tau\setminus Int\,\sigma=\tau$. It is a close set.
Case 2:$\tau \cap\sigma=\sigma,\tau\setminus Int\,\sigma=Bd\,\sigma$.It is a close set.
Case 3:$\tau \cap\sigma=s,s\in K,s\neq\sigma,\tau\setminus Int\,\sigma=\tau.$
Hence, $\tau\cap(\lvert K\rvert\setminus Int\,\sigma)$ is a close set. $\lvert K\rvert\setminus Int\,\sigma$ is a close set.
Therefore, Int$\,\sigma$ is always open in $\lvert K\rvert$.
(2)I try to argue as in (1),but when I attempt to discuss the case that $\tau\cap\sigma\neq\emptyset$, I failed.
Since $\sigma$ is closed in $\lvert K\rvert$ as well, I guess maybe $\sigma$ is open iff $\sigma=\lvert K\rvert$.
Is my answer to (1) correct?How can i deal with the second question?Thank you for your help.

For (1), if $|K|$ is a triangle, obtained by a simplicial complex with 3 vertices, 3 edges, and one $2$-simplex, you're saying that the interior of each edge is open in $|K|$? Also, what is the definition of the interior of a $0$-simplex? For (2), what if $|K|$ consists just of two points?

@John Palmieri Thank you for your comment. I have knew that there is something wrong with my proof and idea for (1) and (2). However, i am still unable to find the mistake in my proof for (1). Could you please tell me where is wrong for the proof of (1) and how can deal with (1)(2).

For both cases, draw some examples — examples in the plane should be fine for this — and see what happens.

I will answer your first question (one question per post please).
Your error is in Case 2.
Doing case 2, suppose that $\sigma$ is a lower dimensional face of $\tau$, then $\tau \setminus \text{int} \, \sigma$ is not a closed set.
For example, suppose that $\tau$ is the $2$-simplex represented in the plane as the right triangle with vertices $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(0,1)$. Suppose also that $\sigma$ is the 1-simplex represented as the line segment $BC$, which is the hypotenuse of the triangle. The $\tau \setminus \text{int} \, \sigma$ is obtained from $\tau$ by removing the interior points of the hypotenuse (which is not the same as $\text{Bd} \, \sigma$, because it also contains all of the points of $\tau$ that are not on the hypotenuse). But that is not a closed subset of $\tau$; the closure of that subset contains all of those points you removed.

I think you're addressing case 2, not case 3. (But I agree that this is the flaw.)

Case 2 is actually subsumed in Case 3, but yeah. I'll rewrite it.

In case 3, I'm thinking of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ being, for example, edges that meet at a vertex, in which case the conclusion of case 3 is correct. I think that in case 3 in general, the interior of $\sigma$ does not intersect $\tau$, whereas in case 2, the interior of $\sigma$ is contained in $\tau$.

There is a general convention in topology that the interior of a 0-simplex is the whole of that 0-simplex. This convention follows the definitions of interior points and boundary points in the context of a manifold-with-boundary.

I understand that, but in case 3, $\tau \cap \sigma$ is a proper face of $\sigma$, so $\sigma$ is not a $0$-simplex. When you have an $n$-simplex $\sigma$ with $n>0$, the interior of $\sigma$ is obtained by removing all of its proper faces, and so in case 3, $\tau$ will not intersect the interior of $\sigma$. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Ohhh, I'm sorry, now I see what you are saying. No, you are absolutely correct. My fault for being too careless.
